# Why the ResultSet is closed?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm struggling with parsing an element I get from the SQLite database, but got exception "ResultSet is closed" thrown. Earlier I had used one statement for all queries, but I've learnt it can cause the problem so I created the statement locally. I still get the same error.

```
private Book parseBook(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
    return new Book(result.getString(1), result.getString(2), result.getString(3), 
            LocalDate.parse(result.getString(4)), result.getString(5), result.getString(6));
}

@Override
public Book getBook(String id) throws SQLException {
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = String.format(selectBooks, id);
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    return parseBook(result);
}
```

The getBook() function is called in Main by: `Book data = sqlDAO.getBook(args[1]);`

Here's the full error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.checkOpen(CoreResultSet.java:69)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreResultSet.markCol(CoreResultSet.java:96)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:436)
at library.LibrarySQLDAO.parseBook(LibrarySQLDAO.java:37)
at library.LibrarySQLDAO.getBook(LibrarySQLDAO.java:82)
at library.Main.main(Main.java:195)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've seen posts with the same error, but in all I've seen the problem was re-using one statement incorrectly. Please give me a hint what do I do wrongly.

Comment: you need to post parseBook and indicate line 37

Comment: @SharonBenAsher what do you mean?

Comment: the stack trace specifies that the exception occurs inside parseBook method, at line 37. so show the source code of this method and point to us the line number.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `result.next()` (even for first row) before getting column values

```
private Book parseBook(ResultSet result) throws SQLException {
    if (result.next()) {
        return new Book(result.getString(1), result.getString(2), result.getString(3), 
            LocalDate.parse(result.getString(4)), result.getString(5), result.getString(6));
    }
    return null; // return empty book?
}
```